# What does the offset mean in BCC

Tags: ebpf, bcc-bpf

I've been using BCC to profile my code.
As part of it I'm looking at the offset we get when using the sym() function, which gets a function name from an address and a pid, and optionally displays the offset.

I got the following results when profiling with the profile.py tool :

```
  count1e8  offset  54
     main  offset  100
     __libc_start_main  offset  231
[unknown]
    -                profile (7446)
        9
```

I tweaked the output a little bit to read the offset in base 10 instead of 16.

I do not understand what the offset mean in this context, the doc reads as 'instruction offset from the beginning of the symbol', but I can't match the offsets from the output with any files (source, asm, elf).
How do I read count1e8 offset 54?

The goal would ultimately be to trace back this offset to either the ASM instruction or the source file line which originated this instruction.

Comment: How did you try to match it with the asm? It's a number of instructions so that should work.